# How to stop script resizing border box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever clicking the buttons to complete the sum, the box automatically resizes. I want to make sure the box remains a certain shape and doesn't adjust when the buttons are clicked.

I've tried padding eat and none seems to work. Rather new to `css` so excuse any obvious errors!

This is my `css` as I can't upload the photo because of the limit:

```css
div {
     border-style: solid;
     text-align: center;
     background: white;
     border-width: 5px;
     width: 300px;
     margin-left: 450px;
     margin-top: 50px;
     padding: 50px 50px 100px 50px;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px gray;

}
```

[the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHEdP.png)

[the script, just repeated near identically for each button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcuhm.png)

Comment: Please post your code here. We can't help with just an image!

Comment: @BenM please sign first the nda

Comment: You should also post your CSS...

Comment: @webdeb, he posted the CSS. He should post the JavaScript code and the HTML, not the images of that code like he did.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a normalize.css or a reset.css

Just include it in you html like other css files

https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/